# How to sort data fetching from cloud firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a service to fetch the data from my firestore collection and now what i want to do is to sort the documents by one of the fields say "date"
Attaching codes below:

**BARCODE.SERVICE.TS**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Barcode } from '../models/barcode';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BarcodeService {
  barcodesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Barcode>;
  barcodes: Observable<Barcode[]>;
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.barcodesCollection = this.afs.collection('barcodes');

    this.barcodes = this.barcodesCollection.valueChanges();
  }
  getBarcodes(){
    this.barcodes = this.afs.collection('barcodes').valueChanges();
    return this.barcodes;
  }

  addBarcode(barcode: Barcode) {
    this.barcodesCollection.add(barcode);
  }
}
```

**COMPONENT.TS** (only showing required part)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.barcodeService.getBarcodes().subscribe(barcodes => {
      this.barcodes = barcodes;
    });
  }
```

**COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="barcodes.length > 0;else noBarcodes">
        <div *ngFor="let barcode of barcodes">
            <a (click)="viewdet(barcode.id)"><table >
                    <tr>
                        <td><h3 class="big"><b>{{barcode.vendor}}</b></h3></td>
                        <td rowspan="3"><span>&#8250;</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h3><b>Reel No:</b> {{barcode.reelno}}</h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h3><b>Date:</b> {{barcode.date}}</h3></td>
                    </tr>


            </table></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `this.barcodeService.getBarcodes().pipe(map(barcodes => barcodes.slice().sort((x, y) => new Date(x.date).valueOf() - new Date(y).valueOf()))).subscribe(barcodes => {this.barcodes = barcodes})`

Comment: can you please post as an answer , i am not able to understand where to use this code

Comment: It's the body of your `ngOnInit()`. It's so trivial and I'm not going to test it. The idea is to sort the barcodes.

Comment: getting this  ```error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Barcode[]>'. ```

Comment: I had a typo, fixed

Comment: getting same error again alongwith -
error TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Barcode[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: it is still not solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md), the following should work (not tested however):

```
  getBarcodes(){
    this.barcodes = this.afs.collection('barcodes', ref => ref.orderBy('date')).valueChanges();
    return this.barcodes;
  }
```